How can I solve ":app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions"
I want to use Jetpack Compose to create my android APP, but I create a new APP, and I tried to run it, but I get this error. named :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions, and It has 112 errors, it's crazy.
This is my build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.mypde"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.mypde"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.7.2")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

This is my settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url=uri("https://jitpack.io") }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "MyPDE"
include(":app")
 

This is my MainActivity.kt
package com.example.mypde

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity
import com.example.mypde.ui.theme.MyPDETheme

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyPDETheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyPDETheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}

It's so unbelieveable that I found this code was wrong "import androidx.activity.compose.setContent", it said, "Unresolved references: activity"
I made a new android APP, why I get those errors ?
My java version is 17, so I edited these codes.
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

How can i solve those errors ?
